# Répondre à une invitation pour un entretien

Tags: correspondance, email, formulation

Je viens de recevoir le mail suivant de la part d'un recruteur:

> Suite à votre demande d’emploi , nous tenons à vous informer que votre
>   candidature a été bien acceptée. Pour cela nous nous permettons par la
>   présente convocation de vous inviter pour passer un entretien
>   d’embauche direct avec l’un de nos consultants en ressources humaines
>   le Lundi 11 Juillet 2016 Veuillez vous présenter à l’adresse suivante
>   :Boulevard XYZ, Ville ABC. En cas de désistement non désiré, merci de
>   le signaler sur le numéro suivant : le 06-73.65.13.64 .pour
>   l'obtention d'un autre R.D.V Une fois à la réception vous demandez Mr
>   X.

Questions:

1. Dois-je répondre à cet email?
2. Si oui, est ce que cette réponse est appropriée?:

Bonjour Monsieur X,

> J'accuse réception de votre mail et vous remercie pour l’intérêt que
>   vous avez porté à ma candidature.
>
> Je viens par le présent confirmer ma présence à l'entretien le Lundi
>   11 Juillet à ladite adresse. De ce fait, Je vous prie de me
>   communiquer l'heure qui vous convient.
>
> Si de plus amples informations vous semble nécessaires a mon encontre,
>   n’hésitez pas a me contacter. Je me mets a votre entière disposition.
>
> Cordialement,

NB: j'ai indique mon adresse mail dans ma réponse parce que j'ai postulé via un site d'annonces gratuites qui cache les adresses mails.

3. Le recruteur n'a pas indiqué l'heure, est-il approprié de lui demander de la manière dont j'ai fait?
4. Je doute de plusieurs formules utilisées dans ma réponse. Je vous prie de me corriger si possible (Je sais que SE n'est pas l'endroit ou demander de tels choses mais toute détection de malformulation est très appréciée)

Merci pour votre temps et vos conseils.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

En corrigeant les quelques fautes et en évitant les répétitions/tournures un peu étranges/lourdeurs inutiles, cela donne quelque chose comme :

> Bonjour Monsieur X,
>
> J'accuse réception de votre mail et vous remercie pour l’intérêt que
>   vous avez porté à ma candidature.
>
> Je confirme ma présence à l'entretien prévu le lundi
>   11 juillet à l'adresse indiquée. Pouvez-vous, s'il vous plaît, m'indiquer l'horaire qui vous convient le mieux ?
>
> Si de plus amples informations me concernant vous semblent nécessaires,
>   je reste à votre entière disposition à l'adresse
>   email@hotmail.fr.
>
> Cordialement,
>
> Monsieur Y.

Dans l'absolu, un mail ne s'écrit pas comme une lettre. Le but ici est d'être le plus concis possible (la plupart des mails qui contiennent des paragraphes de plus de quatre ou cinq lignes ne sont tout bonnement pas lus par manque de temps) tout en restant courtois et clair.

Aux yeux de certains recruteurs, l'échange de tels mails prouve l'aptitude à la concision et l'efficacité. Se forcer à l'exercice n'a donc que du bon.

Comment: Je trouve que la suggestion est appropriée et le commentaire pertinent. D'autant que l'émail reçu ressemble à un émail automatique.

Comment: Merci Matt, j'ai appris beaucoup de choses en regardant tes corrections et les differences. Le commentaire est aussi pertinent. Merci @Rémi également. Pour ce qui est de la forme de l'email recu, le site d'annonce intermédiaire reformate le message, ce qui le rend sous format d'un seul paragraphe.

Answer (score 1):

Tout dépendamment de l'endroit où tu as postulé le ton et le langage utilisé peut changer. De ce que je vois de ton courriel, l'endroit est assez sérieux. Si au contraire l'endroit est un peu plus décontracté comme une compagnie de jeux vidéo ou un autre endroit où l'étiquette est plus ou moins stricte, je conseille peut-être d'utiliser un ton plus décontracté. Une bonne règle à suivre est la règle du +1. Regarde l'endroit et leur niveau de sérieux et rajoute +1. Sois donc toujours un peu plus sérieux que la compagnie qui t'engage. C'est un truc qui est très souvent méconnu par plusieurs personnes et qui s'applique aussi à la façon de s'habiller pour une entrevue.

Au final, je trouve ta lettre parfaite et très professionnelle. J'ai déjà postulé pour des postes très importants (Gouvernemental/Militaire) avec des courriels beaucoup moins bien écrits que cela. (J'ai obtenu chaque emploi auquel j'ai postulé.)

C'est mon simple avis.

Comment: Merci Master D.C votre réponse est a la fois constructive et reconforante.